# $state.go does not change state due to error

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

These are my state definitions:

```
$stateProvider
            .state('schoolyears', {
                url: '/schoolyears',
                templateUrl: '../views/schoolyears.html',
                controller: 'SchoolyearsController'
            })
            .state('schoolyears.selected', {
                url: '/:schoolyearId'
            })
```

Inside the SchoolyearsController I call $state.go when the selection of a row in the datagrid changes:

```
 $scope.myOptions = {
        data: 'myData',
        multiSelect: false,
        selectedItems: [],
        afterSelectionChange: function (rowItem) {
            if (rowItem.selected) {
                $state.go('schoolyears.selected({ schoolyearId:' + rowItem.entity.schoolyearId + '}');
            }
        }};
```

Nothing happens in the url because in my browser console I have this error:

```
Error: Could not resolve 'schoolyears.selected({ schoolyearId:43}' from state 'schoolyears'
```

What I want is that the url changes to:

```
/#/schoolyears/43
```

Why can I not change the url?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside the SchoolyearsController change:

```
afterSelectionChange: function (rowItem) {
        if (rowItem.selected) {
            $state.go('schoolyears.selected({ schoolyearId:' + rowItem.entity.schoolyearId + '}');
        }
    }};
```

to:

```
afterSelectionChange: function (rowItem) {
        if (rowItem.selected) {
            $state.go('schoolyears.selected',{ schoolyearId: rowItem.entity.schoolyearId });
        }
    }};
```

As `$state.go` can be overloaded with two parameters in this instance, for more information please see the [api reference](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)

Comment: Looks like you've got an extra set of brackets around the second parameter to `state.go`?

Comment: You're right Spence, thanks for catching that one :)